# Matplotlib.FuncAnimation working but with strange Exception when using `interval = ... < 200`

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am trying to show an animation of a travelling wave (Bichromatic type) using Matplotlib. The function is presented below, and it works but with a strange Error when we set the `interval=...` paramater less than the default value `200`. Why, and how to remove this? Thanks.

```
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=numpy.linspace(0, 60, 20*60),
                    init_func=init, blit = True, interval = 10)`
```

The error says:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1553, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 599, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 147, in _on_timer
    TimerBase._on_timer(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1305, in _on_timer
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1021, in _step
    still_going = Animation._step(self, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 827, in _step
    self._draw_next_frame(framedata, self._blit)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 845, in _draw_next_frame
    self._pre_draw(framedata, blit)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 858, in _pre_draw
    self._blit_clear(self._drawn_artists, self._blit_cache)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 898, in _blit_clear
    a.figure.canvas.restore_region(bg_cache[a])
KeyError: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0xb1599eac>
```

---

**Imports :**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy

cos = numpy.cos; sin = numpy.sin;
```

**Main function :**

```
def bichromatic_wave_anim():

    amp = [1, 2]
    mode = ['cos', 'cos']
    phase_speed = [0.6, 0.8]
    frq = [35, 38]

    def func(x, amp, mode, frq, shift):
        y = [ amp*getattr(numpy, mode)(frq*(i-shift)) \
              for i in x ]
        return y

    N = 2000
    xl = 0; xr = 10
    dx = (xr-xl)/(N-1)
    x = [ xl + i*(xr-xl)/(N-1) for i in range(N) ]
    buoy_point = 2

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)

    plot1, = ax[0].plot(x, func(x, amp[0], mode[0], frq[0], 0), \
                            '-', color = 'blue', lw = 1, \
                            animated = True)
    plot2, = ax[0].plot(x, func(x, amp[1], mode[1], frq[1], 0), \
                            '-', color = 'red', lw = 1, \
                            animated = True)
    bichromplot, = ax[1].plot(x, [ i+j for i,j in zip(func(x, amp[0], mode[0], frq[0], 0), func(x, amp[1], mode[1], frq[1], 0)) ], \
                                  '-', color = 'purple', lw = 2, \
                                  animated = True)
    buoy, = ax[1].plot([buoy_point], func([buoy_point], amp[0], mode[0], frq[0], 0)[0] + \
                                     func([buoy_point], amp[1], mode[1], frq[1], 0)[0], \
                                  marker = 'o', markeredgecolor = (0,0,0,0), ms = 12, color = 'orange', \
                                  animated = True)

    def init():
        ax[0].set_xlabel(r'$x$')
        ax[1].set_xlabel(r'$x$')

        ax[0].set_ylabel('Two monochromatic waves', \
                  )
        ax[1].set_ylabel(r'A bichromatic wave: ${}\{}({}x) + {}\{}({}x)$'.format(amp[0], mode[0], frq[0], amp[1], mode[1], frq[1]),\
                   )

        ax[0].legend(labels = [ r'${}\{}({}x)$'.format(i, j, k) for i, j, k in zip(amp, mode, frq) ])

        return [plot1, plot2, bichromplot, buoy]

    def update(frame):
        y1 = func(x, amp[0], mode[0], frq[0], phase_speed[0]*frame)
        y2 = func(x, amp[1], mode[1], frq[1], phase_speed[1]*frame)
        ybichrom = [ i+j for i,j in zip(func(x, amp[0], mode[0], frq[0], phase_speed[0]*frame), func(x, amp[1], mode[1], frq[1], phase_speed[1]*frame)) ]
        ybuoy = func([buoy_point], amp[0], mode[0], frq[0], phase_speed[0]*frame)[0] + \
                                     func([buoy_point], amp[1], mode[1], frq[1], phase_speed[1]*frame)[0] 
        plot1.set_data(x, y1)
        plot2.set_data(x, y2)
        bichromplot.set_data(x, ybichrom)
        buoy.set_data([buoy_point], ybuoy)

        return [plot1, plot2, bichromplot, buoy]

    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=numpy.linspace(0, 60, 20*60),
                    init_func=init, blit = True, interval = 10) ## 'interval' can only be greater than 200 in order to remove the Error.

    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.show()

    return anim

anim = bichromatic_wave_anim()
```

Comment: Your code does not show an animation. You must keep the reference to `anim` alive for it to work. I'm editing your code so that it works. From the docs (https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html): "In both cases it is critical to keep a reference to the instance object. The animation is advanced by a timer (typically from the host GUI framework) which the Animation object holds the only reference to. If you do not hold a reference to the Animation object, it (and hence the timers), will be garbage collected which will stop the animation."

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with Matplotlib 2.2.2 with Qt5Agg backend, Tkinter 81008 and Spyder 3.2.8 (my IDE) on Windows 10. The animation is shown without error when I set `interval=10`. What versions are you using?  Perhaps updating Tkinter and Matplotlib to the latest version will solve it.